# Room returns long but not inserting data in to table - one to many relationship

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i have two entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "TrackingItemTable")
data class TrackingItem(
                        @ColumnInfo val ProductName:String,
                        @ColumnInfo val ProductPrice:Float,
                        @ColumnInfo val ProductImage:String,
                        @ColumnInfo val ProductCurrencySymbol:String,
                        @ColumnInfo val ProductAddedDate: Date,
                        @ColumnInfo val ProductSiteName:String,
                        @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo val ProductUrl:String,
                        @ColumnInfo val ProductAffiliateUrl:String,
                        @ColumnInfo var ProductNotificationPrice:Float? = null,
                        @ColumnInfo var ProductLastUpdatedPrice:Float
)
```

and it has an foregin key relationship with the other entity

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(entity = TrackingItem::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("ProductUrl"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("ProductAnalyticsUrl"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)), tableName = "TrackingItemDataTable")



data class TrackingItemData(@ColumnInfo val ProductAnalyticsUrl:String,
                            @ColumnInfo val Price:Float,
                            @ColumnInfo val Date: Long,
                            @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo var id:Int = 0
)
```

whenever i try to insert a row in to the TrackingItemData table, the row didnt get inserted, however the room returns a Long value,here is my dao

```
@Dao
interface TrackingItemDataDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertTrackingItemData(trackingItemData:TrackingItemData): Single<Long>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM TrackingItemDataTable")
    fun getAllTrackingItems():LiveData<List<TrackingItemData>>

}
```

and i insert the data like this

```
Db.analyticsDao().insertTrackingItemData(
    TrackingItemData(ProductAnalyticsUrl = url,
        Price = currentPrice,
        Date = currentTime))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
        Log.d("shopzy", it.toString())
    },{
        Log.d("shopzy", it.toString())
    })
```

the throwable of rx java didnt catch any exceptions, the code print the long value, but when i download the db from emulator and see the table i dont find a row in it, and getAllTrackingItems() from the dao returns 0 rows, what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason removing  tableName = "TrackingItemDataTable" from the second entity class solved the problem, not sure why it did